# python returning a strangely formatted string

Tags: python, ansible, python-2.x

I'm trying to edit a Python module, but I'm not getting the value I expect from a variable.  The code is:

```
    def populate_ipv4_interfaces(self, data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        vrf = re.findall(r'VPN Routing/Forwarding "(.+)"', value)
```

where I'm expecting a string value to be output.  It does contain my string, but something else.  When I force it to be a string like this:

```
vrf = str(re.findall(r'VPN Routing/Forwarding "(.+)"', value))
```

gives me the value "[u'Internet']" instead of "Internet".

I've looked up the u, and I realise this denotes a unicode character, but I don't know why it's pulling that information along with the string.

If it helps, this is an ansible module, but I've narrowed it down to this one variable, since if I specify a string in the fact instead of this variable, everything works as intended.

Can someone tell me why I'm seeing this behaviour?

Comment: "where I'm expecting a string value to be output" - [`re.findall` returns a list](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#re.findall).

Answer (score 2):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list of results - even if there is only one result.

And unicode strings are still strings. It should behave the same for all puposes.

So the result you are looking for is:

```
vrf = re.findall(r'VPN Routing/Forwarding "(.+)"', value)[0]
```

Don't use the `str` on the result directly.

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall()` returns a list, so use a join for getting them:

```
vrf = ' '.join(re.findall(r'VPN Routing/Forwarding "(.+)"', value))
```

Other way use list indexing to get first item:

```
vrf = re.findall(r'VPN Routing/Forwarding "(.+)"', value)[0]
```